# Why I can not use ssh to clone while https works?

Tags: git, ssh, https, proxy

All:

I am pretty new to networking. I am behind office firewall, when I use git, I can only use https to clone the repository but not ssh, I wonder if anyone could give me some detail why?

Thanks

Comment: The suspicion goes firstly to the firewall. Maybe the port 22 is blocked. What error message do you get when you try to clone using ssh?

Comment: @Jodevan ssh: connect to host aaa.bbb.com port 22: Connection timed out

Comment: Assuming the host address is correct and it's up, it looks like the firewall is the culprit. It's strange though. Why would they block outbound ssh connections? Have you tried to connect to any other ssh server using another tool, like putty? You might as well give it a try. If you're unable to, for sure is the firewall, although it does make much sense to me.

Comment: I can use MobaXterm to connect( which specify 1. proxy credential and 2. ssh server credential and 3. private key  ) , but actually what I need is to make git work with ssh( I need to clone my repo from rhcloud.com but they do not have https clone).

Comment: Right, but it'd be important to you if your network is blocking the connection, right? That's why my suggestion would be to you try to connect to another ssh server. If you can't, that means the firewall should be blocking outbound ssh connections or maybe the domain you want to connect to. You could even try to connect to your git server from another network too. If it works, once more the culprit is the firewall.

Comment: @Jodevan Thanks, I did not quite get ur point, "I CAN use MobaXterm to connect" to that ssh server, but no luck with using git.